# Check if Value exists in Specific Row

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have this table

```
Num |  id1  |  id2  |  id3
---------------------------
1   |  abc  |  sjs  |  hss    
2   |  abc  |  sjs  |  hss    
3   |  sjs  |  hss  |  uaj     
4   |  ahs  |  shh  |  ajs    
5   |  dks  |  sns  |  jaj


$user = "3";
$value = "hss";
```

I want to check if VALUE is present in row of USER or not (only I want to check in row which is in front of USER value not other rows or columns) How can I check?

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  What does `$user` have to do with the table.  What VALUE is present in what row and where?

Comment: is a `user` a bit like a `num`

Comment: Sorry sir. I user means the ID NUMBER. I want to check if my value is present in front of that ID NUMBER. Or in that row!

Comment: Yes user is the I'd number

Comment: What database do you use? Mysql, Oracle, SqlServer? Is the table in it or the table is in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple query to do what you need would be;

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE 'hss' IN (id1, id2, id3)
  AND num <= 3;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62e2f9/4).